# Searching for a distributed algorithm to distribute some objects

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, implementation, distribution, distributed-computing

I'm searching an algorithm to solve the following problem:

There are `n` software components which are able to communicate over multicast. Moreover there is a pool with `m` objects. Every sw component knows what that pool contains.
The objects have different values. Depending on the value I want to distribute the objects to the sw components. That means: objects with a greater value have to be preferred, objects with a lower value have to be neglected (for example when all sw components can't take more objects).

It is very important, that no object is distributed more than once. When one object is assigned to a sw component it must not be assigned to another sw component.

Furthermore I want to implement the whole thing as a distributed algorithm, that means without a central unit which executes that distribution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not have each software component check the pool and take the highest value object?

Comment: yes but the problem is to guarantee that no object is distributed more than once.

Comment: That completely depends on the nature of your pool.  For example, is there one system on the network in charge of the pool, and the other software components ask it for an object?  Or, is the pool just a list maintained by each of the software components, and they all must communicate with each other to keep their versions of the pool in sync?

Comment: It's the second: "a list maintained by each of the software components, and they all must communicate with each other to keep their versions of the pool in sync"

Answer (score 0):

1. One solution would be to implement a mutual exclusion algorithm (a very simple one is bakery algorithm) and each sw takes the highest object when it's turn comes. (This is like mutual exclusion for writing to files)
2. Another one would involve a lot of communication between nodes. Let's suppose the general case where N>=M. Suppose each sw takes n/m components then he takes the highest value and multicasts the rest of the x components to x sw but with and additional value that is the max of those components *casted. The receiving sw will then see if their value is bigger then those received and will exchange it and delete that value from the list but insert it;s old value. Then it will cast the components with the max calculated to the same x sw components. The idea is that the set X of sw will communicate with each other until every node has a different value. You will have a few of this X sets. Of course this algorithm must be refined so every sw has a different value and to prove that this will happed so you can be sure.

But you wanted and idea so I gave you 2. Hope it helps.
The implementation of the algorithm would be in OpenMPI (with C or C++). At least I implemented my distributed algorithms in OpenMPI (and Lam MPI but now it's obsolete).